# Get phone number of SMS sender, using Twilio

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I am trying to retrieve the phone number of a user who sends SMS to my Twilio number, but I can't fetch it in my program.

I have tried these:

```
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->get("$Smssid");
$number = $message->From;
```

But no matter what I try `$number` is still blank. I have tried to get `$sid`, `sid`, `$SMSSid`. Nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may not be the issue, but did you try lowercasing the 'from' property? Their API shows it lowercase.

Comment: Also, have you tried retrieving any other data (body, date_sent)? If so, did it work?

Comment: Tried the lowercase - doesn't work. still blank. body doesn't work either. I used $message = $client->account->sms_messages->sid;
$reply = $message->body;

Comment: Are you displaying errors on your page so you can see what's going on with your code? And did you check the error_log?

Comment: Right now, I am using the following code: $message = $client->account->sms_messages->smssid;
$reply = $message->from;  

I then send an SMS to myself with $reply. I should see my own number. The SMS is blank.

Comment: The error log says - Error on line 2 of document : Premature end of file. Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document.

Comment: You're probably going to have to post more of your code. That error is too general, and there's only two lines of code to go off of.

Comment: Here is the pastebin of the codes - http://pastebin.com/MLXqws1T

Answer (score 1):

When a user sends you an SMS, we make an HTTP request to your server. This HTTP request contains info about the SMS, such as the From, To, Body, etc.

To retrieve the 'From' value from the HTTP request in PHP, simply do the following:

```
$from_number = $_REQUEST['From'];
```

Alternately you can retrieve it from the REST API:

```
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->get($_REQUEST['SmsSid'])
```

Although this should be unneccessary as all the data you need should be in the HTTP request.

Comment: When you have the $message bit, you should use 'from' instead of 'From. You can see an example in the snippets here: https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/sms-messages.html#listing-sms-messages

Comment: Tried to use request.GET and POST in Django bit didn't see any data.

Comment: @CaseySoftware, your link is broken